# Oracle APEX - views to determine if a breadcrumb is used anywhere

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

In the past I have used APEX views to determine if a page item is used anywhere. Is there a view that can be used to check if a specific breadcrumb is being used?

I am trying to clean up some unused objects in my application. I looked at APEX_APPLICATION_BREADCRUMBS and APEX_APPLICATION_BC_ENTRIES but do not see where they are linked to a specific page. Which view do I query to find relationships between page and breadcrumbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy option is to navigate to Shared Components -> Breadcrumbs -> Utilization and you can get the page number where the breadcrumb was used.

[image: Breadcrumb Utilization]

Comment: thanks! That is great. But do you happen to know which APEX application view has that info?

Comment: using APEX_APPLICATION_BC_ENTRIES you can similar information.
Check the DEFINED_FOR_PAGE column.

Comment: I did see that but that does not provide enough information